# Generating Sequence diagram from a method in ObjectAid

Tags: java, android, objectaid

Do anyone know how to generate a Sequence diagram from a method in ObjectAid ?. I couldn't find anything in their website.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new ObjectAid's file and just drag and drop your Eclipse classes on this diagram. After that the program computes relationship, inheritance and so on. Actually this is documented on their [website](http://www.objectaid.com/class-diagram) itself. Make sure you installed it properly and installed the License.

Answer (score 0):

Download the 'ObjectAid UML Explorer' plugin in eclipse marketplace.

Go to - Help -> Install new Software->  paste the url  'http://www.objectaid.net/update'

and download the plugin in eclipse. Once you done with this, restart your eclipse.

1. Choose the project or the class you want to create a class or sequence diagram
2. Right click on the project -> other -> select ObjectAid
3. Under that you will find two options 1. class diagram and 2. sequence diagram

Choose whatever you want and create it. Thanks.